# update hibernate configuration file in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, swing

I want to update my mysql database and alter some tables(add new tables and columns).Is there any way to update the hibernate configuration file and mapping classes and add the entity classes for the newly added table in netbeans IDE without manual coding for swing applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some tools out there to generate hibernate mappings, [like this](http://hibernatepojoge.sourceforge.net/). For netbeans, I think [this link](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ReverseEngineering) might help you.